# Составить программу нахождения и вывода всех целых четырёхзначных чисел, сумма цифр которых равна 22

Tags: java, java-8

Как найти и вывести все целые четырёхзначные числа, сумма цифр которых равна 22?

```
int[] array = new int[9999];
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> i + 1);
for (int i = 999; i<array.length; i++) {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Альтернативный вариант, который может стать актуальным для больших диапазонов - не проверять все числа, а генерировать только те, сумма цифр которых равна нужной (разбиение суммы на n слагаемых, не превышающих 9, последнее ненулевое).

Рекурсивный пример на Python:

```
def NumWithDigSum(n, summ):
    if (summ <= 0 or summ > 9*n):
        return []
    if (n == 1):
        return [summ]
    res = []
    for i in range(0, min(summ,9) + 1):
        res.extend([i+(x*10) for x in NumWithDigSum(n-1, summ-i)])
    return res

print(NumWithDigSum(3, 17))

>>>[980, 890, 971, 881, 791, 962, 872, 782, 692, 953, 863, 773, 683, 593, 
   944, 854, 764, 674, 584, 494, 935, 845, 755, 665, 575, 485, 395, 926, 
   836, 746, 656, 566, 476, 386, 296, 917, 827, 737, 647, 557, 467, 377, 
   287, 197, 908, 818, 728, 638, 548, 458, 368, 278, 188, 809, 719, 629, 
   539, 449, 359, 269, 179]
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8:

```
public static void findNumbers(){   
  IntStream.range(1000, 10000)
    .filter(i -> String.valueOf(i)
        .chars()
        .map(Character::getNumericValue)
        .sum() == 22)
    .forEach(number -> System.out.println(number));
}
```

Или по старинке:

```
public static void findNumbers(){
  for(int i = 1000; i < 10000; ++i){
    int num = i;

    int sum = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum = sum + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }

    if(sum == 22){
       System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```